# XPath expression selecting element based on another node's value

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

With the following XML, is it possible with an XPath expression to select local item elements where the regional item's amount with the same code is within 5% of the local item's amount? In this example, local item 4 would be selected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Inventory> 
  <Local> 
    <Item> 
      <Code>1</Code>  
      <Amount>10000</Amount> 
    </Item>  
    <Item> 
      <Code>2</Code>  
      <Amount>20000</Amount> 
    </Item>  
    <Item> 
      <Code>3</Code>  
      <Amount>30000</Amount> 
    </Item>  
    <Item> 
      <Code>4</Code>  
      <Amount>40000</Amount> 
    </Item> 
  </Local>  
  <Regional> 
    <Item> 
      <Code>2</Code>  
      <Amount>100</Amount> 
    </Item>  
    <Item> 
      <Code>4</Code>  
      <Amount>39900</Amount> 
    </Item> 
  </Regional> 
</Inventory>
```

So far I am only able to select the local items with the same codes with the expression below, which returns two elements, but I can't seem to figure out how to multiply both elements by 0.95 since adding "/Amount * 0.95" to the end of this expression causes it to return just the first item's amount multiplied by 0.95.

```
/Inventory/Local/Item[Code=/Inventory/Regional/Item/Code]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`xquery`](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_flwor.asp):

#### XQuery

```
for $x in doc("input.xml")//Local/Item
let $y:=doc("input.xml")//Regional/Item[Code=$x/Code]
where $y/Amount*0.95<=$x/Amount and $x/Amount<=$y/Amount*1.05
return $x
```

#### Test in shell

```
$ zorba -q 'for $x in doc("input.xml")//Local/Item let $y:=doc("input.xml")//Regional/Item[Code=$x/Code] where $y/Amount*0.95<=$x/Amount and $x/Amount<=$y/Amount*1.05 return $x'
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item> 
      <Code>4</Code>  
      <Amount>40000</Amount> 
</Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the question quite interesting, have been trying to solve it for the last hour,

here's the solution using **XPATH 2.0**:

```
for $x  in   /Inventory/Local/Item[Code=/Inventory/Regional/Item/Code],
    $y   in   /Inventory/Regional/Item[Code = $x/code]
      return  $x[Amount div 20 <= $y/Amount ]
```

pretty sure this can't be done using an **XPath 1.0 expression**.

Answer (score 0):

**XQuery isn't needed to specify the desired selection**.

**Here is a single XPath 2.0 expression that is correct, shorter and more efficient**:

```
for $locItem in /*/Local/*,
    $locAmount in $locItem/Amount,
    $fivePercent in $locAmount*0.05,
    $regItem in
    /*/Regional/Item
         [Code eq $locItem/Code
        and
         abs(Amount -$locAmount) le $fivePercent
         ]
 return $locItem
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "for $locItem in /*/Local/*,
        $locAmount in $locItem/Amount,
        $fivePercent in $locAmount*0.05,
        $regItem in
        /*/Regional/Item
             [Code eq $locItem/Code
            and
             abs(Amount -$locAmount) le $fivePercent
             ]
     return $locItem"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Inventory>
  <Local>
    <Item>
      <Code>1</Code>
      <Amount>10000</Amount>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Code>2</Code>
      <Amount>20000</Amount>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Code>3</Code>
      <Amount>30000</Amount>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Code>4</Code>
      <Amount>40000</Amount>
    </Item>
  </Local>
  <Regional>
    <Item>
      <Code>2</Code>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Code>4</Code>
      <Amount>39900</Amount>
    </Item>
  </Regional>
</Inventory>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated, and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
<Item>
    <Code>4</Code>
    <Amount>40000</Amount>
</Item>
```